# usePrams showing all params as one paramteter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I creating breadcrumbs that use navigate logic (navigate(-1)) for example so any search parameters that was used will stay there.

the problem i am facing is that i need these breadcrumbs to not include any url parameters.

my routes are essentially set up like this with service providers for various routes. The '/' route has the usenavbar component that has the breadcrumbs being created in there with the useParams

```
        <AuthenticationServiceProvider>
        <BranchServiceProvider>
            <Routes>
                <Route path='/login' element={<LoginPage logoUrl={logo} applicationName="Rail Master" />}></Route>
                <Route path='/' element={<PrivateRoute roles={AuthorizeRoles.USERS} ><RouterPage /></PrivateRoute>}>
                    <Route path='/branch/:branchCode/' element={<PrivateRoute roles={AuthorizeRoles.USERS} ><HomePage /></PrivateRoute>}></Route>
                    <Route path='/branch/:branchCode/config/*' element={<PrivateRoute roles={AuthorizeRoles.ADMINS} ><ConfigurationPage /></PrivateRoute>}></Route>
                    <Route path='/branch/:branchCode/dispatch/*' element={<PrivateRoute roles={AuthorizeRoles.USERS} ><DispatchRouter /></PrivateRoute>}></Route>
                    <Route path='/branch/:branchCode/receive/*' element={<PrivateRoute roles={AuthorizeRoles.USERS} ><HomePage /></PrivateRoute>}></Route>
                    <Route path='/branch' element={<PrivateRoute roles={AuthorizeRoles.USERS} ><HomePage /></PrivateRoute>}></Route>
                    <Route path="*" element={<FourZeroFourPage />} />
                </Route>
                <Route path="*" element={<FourZeroFourPage />} />
            </Routes>
        </BranchServiceProvider>
    </AuthenticationServiceProvider>
```

and the dispatch routes

```
 <DispatchServiceProvider>
            {loading}
            <Scrollbars autoHeight autoHeightMin={window.innerHeight - 100} autoHeightMax={window.innerHeight - 100}>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/" element={canDispatch ? <DispatchPage /> : <Navigate to={'/'} />}></Route>
                    <Route path="/:trainNumber" element={<Navigate to={-1} />}></Route>
                </Routes>
                <DocketServiceProvider>
                    <Routes>
                        <Route path="/:trainNumber/dockets" element={canDispatch ? <DocketsPage /> : <Navigate to={'/'} />}></Route>
                        <Route path="/:trainNumber/dockets/:docketId" element={<Navigate to={-1} />}></Route>
                    </Routes>
                    <ValidateServiceProvider>
                        <Routes>
                            <Route path="/:trainNumber/dockets/:docketId/validate" element={canDispatch ? <ValidatePage /> : <Navigate to={'/'} />}></Route>
                        </Routes>
                    </ValidateServiceProvider>
                    <LogsServiceProvider>
                        <Routes>
                            <Route path="/branch/:branchCode/dispatch/:trainNumber/dockets/:docketId/logs" element={canDispatch ? <LogsPage /> : <Navigate to={'/'} />}></Route>
                        </Routes>
                    </LogsServiceProvider>
                </DocketServiceProvider>
            </Scrollbars>
        </DispatchServiceProvider>
```

the control trying to read the params is in the RoutePage which is simply this. GetNavbar is the one making the call

```
   return (
    <Fragment>
        <GetNavBar />
        <Outlet />
    </Fragment>
);

import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom'
const params = useParams();
```

the response is

```
{
  *:"XX920230328/dockets/6438a6fb794e8f3482f4557c/logs",
  branchCode:"KAW" }
```

any idea on what would cause use params to merge all of them together?

Comment: can you show more about how your router is build and the component that is using useParams

Comment: I agree as I also don't see this as a [mcve]. Since it picked out the `branchCode` path param I'm guessing you've done some route splitting with some nested routes, or similar. Please [edit] the post so we've a clearer idea what is actually being rendered and how they are matched.

Comment: So you are using the `useParams` hook in the `HomePage` component? I don't see where you actually declare/define the rest of the path, so them all being on `"*"` seems to make sense to me.

Comment: sorry, cut and plaster fail. I have the dispatch routes being rendered as a component inside the /dispatch route

Comment: And which component is trying to read the route params? Just a suggestion, all these provider components should be rendered as layout routes so you won't need to wrap each sub-set of routes in another `Routes` component. You could really simplify the routing code by doing this.

Comment: Thank @DrewReese ill look into that. I have updated the post again with the component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean `RouterPage` is the component rendering and using the `useParams` hook then I think the issue is caused by all the routes being split up and rendered as descendent routes. Each `Routes` component acts as a `Switch` ***only*** for the `Route` components it directly renders, and since the parent path is known it can pass ***down*** route path params, but since it can't know what route path params descendent routes may define the *rest* of the URL path is assigned to the splat `"*"`.

See [Splats](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#splats) for more details.

My suggestion here would be to create layout route components for all these providers so they can be integrated more closely to the routing structure. It will remove the need to use descendent routes, you can use nested routes and simplify the routes a bit. The single `Routes` component will be aware of the routes and route path params it is rendering and can correctly access the `branchCode`, `trainNumber`, and `docketId` params.

Example:

```
const AuthenticationBranchServiceLayout = () => (
  <AuthenticationServiceProvider>
    <BranchServiceProvider>
      <Outlet />
    </BranchServiceProvider>
  </AuthenticationServiceProvider>
);
```

```
const DispatchRouter = () => {
  ....

  return (
    <DispatchServiceProvider>
      {loading}
      <Scrollbars
        autoHeight
        autoHeightMin={window.innerHeight - 100}
        autoHeightMax={window.innerHeight - 100}
      >
        <Outlet />
      </Scrollbars>
    </DispatchServiceProvider>
  );
};
```

```
const DocketServiceLayout = () => (
  <DocketServiceProvider>
    <Outlet />
  </DocketServiceProvider>
);

const ValidateServiceLayout = () => (
  <ValidateServiceProvider>
    <Outlet />
  </ValidateServiceProvider>
);

const LogsServiceLayout = () => (
  <LogsServiceProvider>
    <Outlet />
  </LogsServiceProvider>
);
```

Render a single `Routes` component with all the routes rendered into the appropriate layout route.

```
<Routes>
  <Route element={<AuthenticationBranchServiceLayout />}>
    <Route
      path="/login"
      element={<LoginPage logoUrl={logo} applicationName="Rail Master" />}
    />
    <Route
      path="/"
      element={<PrivateRoute roles={AuthorizeRoles.USERS} />}
    >
      <Route element={<RouterPage />}>
        <Route path="branch/:branchCode/" element={<HomePage />} />
        <Route
          path="branch/:branchCode/dispatch"
          element={<DispatchRouter />}
        >
          <Route
            index
            element={
              canDispatch ? <DispatchPage /> : <Navigate to="/" replace />
            }
          />
          <Route path=":trainNumber" element={<Navigate to={-1} />} />
          <Route element={<DocketServiceLayout />}>
            <Route
              path=":trainNumber/dockets"
              element={
                canDispatch ? (
                  <DocketsPage />
                ) : (
                  <Navigate to="/" replace />
                )
              }
            />
            <Route
              path=":trainNumber/dockets/:docketId"
              element={<Navigate to={-1} />}
            />
          </Route>
          <Route element={<ValidateServiceLayout />}>
            <Route
              path=":trainNumber/dockets/:docketId/validate"
              element={
                canDispatch ? (
                  <ValidatePage />
                ) : (
                  <Navigate to="/" replace />
                )
              }
            />
          </Route>
          <Route element={<LogsServiceLayout />}>
            <Route
              path=":trainNumber/dockets/:docketId/logs"
              element={
                canDispatch ? <LogsPage /> : <Navigate to="/" replace />
              }
            />
          </Route>
        </Route>
        <Route
          path="branch/:branchCode/receive/*"
          element={<HomePage />}
        />
        <Route path="branch" element={<HomePage />} />
        <Route element={<PrivateRoute roles={AuthorizeRoles.ADMINS} />}>
          <Route
            path="branch/:branchCode/config/*"
            element={<ConfigurationPage />}
          />
        </Route>
      </Route>
    </Route>
    <Route path="*" element={<FourZeroFourPage />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

[image: Edit useprams-showing-all-params-as-one-paramteter]

[image]